# When Heine - Borel theorem holds

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

If $\cal A$ is an abelian Banach algebra, then its maximal ideal space $\Omega$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

In the proof of this theorem, the author says, since $\Omega \subset ball \cal A^*$, it suffices to show that $\Omega$ is weak* closed.

My question: Why does  Heine - Borel theorem hold in $\cal A^*$?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right naming here would not be "Heine-Borel" but "Banach-Alaoglu".

Comment: You are welcome.